# Dart use `this` inside a Map like on Javascript

Tags: javascript, dart

In `javascript` we can do something like this :

```
var x = {
  'name' : 'john',
  'modifiedName' : function () { return this.name + ' <- modified'}
};
```

so x.modifiedName() returns `john <- modified`

How to do that on `dart` ?

I want to use some of the value from a `Map` to return a value for a key, like the `javascript` example.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to create a Dart class for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with map literals. But you can make your own map class, and there you have multiple ways to achieve this.

**As method**

```
import "dart:collection";

class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap {

  String modifiedName() {
    String name = this["name"];
    return "$name <- modified";
  }

}

void main() {
  MyMap map = new MyMap();
  map["name"] = "John";
  print(map.modifiedName());
  map["name"] = "Harry";
  print(map.modifiedName());
}
```

**As property**

```
import "dart:collection";

class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap {

  String _modifiedName() {
    String name = this["name"];
    return "$name <- modified";
  }

  String get modifiedName => _modifiedName();

}

void main() {

  MyMap map = new MyMap();
  map["name"] = "John";
  print(map.modifiedName);
  map["name"] = "Harry";
  print(map.modifiedName);

}
```

**As map key**

```
import "dart:collection";

class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap {

  String operator [](String key) {
    if(key == "modifiedName") {
      String n = this["name"];
      return "$n <- modified";
    }
    return super[key];
  }

}

void main() {

  MyMap map = new MyMap();
  map["name"] = "John";
  print(map["modifiedName"]);
  map["name"] = "Harry";
  print(map["modifiedName"]);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do it this way:

```dart
var x;
x = {
    'name' : 'john',
    'modifiedName' : () => x['name'] + ' <- modified'
};
print(x['modifiedName']());
```

So, instead of `this` you can just use `x`, as long as you use `x` after it has been declared.